# Автоматическое добавления данных из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: python, django

Помогите пожалуйста, я новичок в Python. У меня есть две модели в Django.

```
class OneTable(models.Model):
    one_column = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=True)
    two_column = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=True)

class TwoTable(models.Model):
    one_column = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=True)
    two_column = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=True)
```

Как сделать чтобы при добавления данных в одну таблицу, данные автоматически добавлялись в третьею таблицу
Пример: чтобы в БД появилась таблица с значениями:

```
thretable:
           |id|       |onetable_id|     |onetable_id|   |thre_column|
            
            1              1                 1          01.01.2021 00:00

            2              2                 2          01.01.2021 00:05
```

Вот что я попытался сделать.

```
class ThreeTable(models.Model):
    one_column = models.ForeignKey(OneTable, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    two_column = models.ForeignKey(TwoTable, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    thre_column = model.models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Но при добавления данных в таблицу OneTable, автоматический запись в таблице ThreeTable не создается.
Я так понимаю что мне нужно как то сделать так, что бы данные из таблицы OneTable отправлялись в таблицу ThreeTable.

Comment: а зачем дублировать? может правильнее было бы обойтись без этого

Comment: Потому что у меня много будет таблиц, но мне нужно чтобы у них было при добавления данных  в них, было у всех таблиц одно значения даты и время.
Но если есть способ лучше напишите плизз.

Comment: И при обращения к этой таблице, она ссылалась к данным с других таблиц.

Comment: ну тут от данных зависит все

Comment: у вас должна быть ОДНА таблица с данными, которые используют другие классы, а не множество одинаковых таблиц, дублирующихся в каждом классе.